# DJI MobileSDK I want to specify the distance with VirtualStick

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I want to move forward by specifying a distance of 5 meters.

I want to know the relationship between the unit of the value of mPitch, mRoll, mYaw, and mThrottle specified by the argument of mFlightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData and the flight distance.

What value must be set for mRoll to advance MAVIC by 5 meters?

I want to know the calculation method.

This is the example code.

```
// What value must be set for mRoll to advance MAVIC by 5 meters?
float distance = 0.5f;

float rollJoyControlMaxSpeed = 10;

float mPitch = 0.0f;
float mRoll = (float)(rollJoyControlMaxSpeed * distance);
float mYaw = 0.0f;
float mThrottle = 0.0f;

mFlightController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(
        new FlightControlData(
                mPitch, mRoll, mYaw, mThrottle
        ), new CommonCallbacks.CompletionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                if (djiError!=null){
                    setResultToToast(djiError.getDescription());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is inertial navigation and the DJI SDK contains no class or function for that at the moment.

In inertial navigation the standard approach is to use the velocity and acceleration in order to calculate the distance moved so far.
The velocity is provided by FlightControllerStateCallback:

```
aircraft.getFlightController().setStateCallback(new FlightControllerState.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdate(@NonNull FlightControllerState flightControllerState) {

            //get current velocity
            float velocityX = flightControllerState.getVelocityX();
            float velocityY = flightControllerState.getVelocityY();
            float velocityZ = flightControllerState.getVelocityZ();

        }
    });
```

The acceleration values are not accessible.
In theory you need to fly at a speed of 1 m/s for 5 seconds to reach your goal of 5 meters. In reality you need to account for the acceleration and braking distance.

The most promising approach I see is to test how much time the Mavic needs to accelerate to a certain speed and also how long the braking distance is in relation to the speed. Based on these you should be able to approximate the distance flown at an acceptable level. Here's some pseudocode of how I imagine it to be working:

```
set velocity to 1 m/s
-> the drone needs 2 seconds to achieve the speed and will fly 1.5m during that time. [1]
once the velocity has been reached(information from callback), wait 2 seconds.
-> the drone flies 2m
set velocity to 0
-> the braking distance for 1m/s is 1.5m [1]

the total distance flown: 5m
```

Please note that these values [1] are purely made up and you need to get approximate values for these via probably tedious testing.